# Override default offering in RevenueCat

Tags: react-native, revenuecat

I am integrating in-app purchases in a React Native app using RevenueCat. My use case requires users to be able to buy multiple entitlements, each from its own separate offering/paywall.

The problem I'm having is that the paywall presented to a user is always either the site-wide default, or the manually-overridden default for that particular user. This happens even when I pass `offering` and `requiredEntitlementIdentifier` to `presentPaywall()` or `presentPaywallIfNeeded()`.

My expected behaviour for this is that passing an offering ID to `presentPaywall()` should override any defaults.

Amy I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through the code for `react-native-purchases` on Github, I have found the issue. `presentPaywall()` does not accept the offering identifier, it must receive the actual offering object.

It would be nice if this were documented.